# Nested XMLHttpRequests in extension not working

Tags: javascript, ajax, google-chrome-extension

The following reads data from a json file generated by a database call.

```
function loadJSON(callback) {   
  var xobj = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xobj.overrideMimeType("application/json");
  xobj.open('GET', 'next.php', true);
  xobj.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (xobj.readyState == 4 && xobj.status == "200") {
      callback(JSON.parse(xobj.responseText));
    }
  };
  xobj.send(null);  
}
```

The following uses the above function to select a random url and change the url when user clicks button.

```
var page = '';
var nextpageButton = document.getElementById('nextpage');
nextpageButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
  loadJSON(function(json) {
    var limit = json.length;
    var i = ((Math.floor(Math.random()*limit)+1) - 1);
    page = (json[i].sites);
    chrome.tabs.query({currentWindow: true, active: true}, function (tab) {
      chrome.tabs.update(tab.id, {url: page});
    });
  });
});
```

Both above functions work perfectly.

The following adds data to databse when the user clicks button. This works perfectly as long as I don't add a nested XMLHttpRequest on success.

```
var like = document.getElementById('tu');
like.addEventListener('click', function() {
  var select_element = document.getElementById('cat');
  var cat = select_element.value;
  if (cat != 0) {
    chrome.tabs.query({active: true, lastFocusedWindow: true}, tabs => {
      var current_url = tabs[0].url;
      var current_title = tabs[0].title;
      var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xhttp.open("POST", "add.php", true);
      xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
      xhttp.send("sites="+current_url+"&title="+current_title+"&vote_up=1&vote_down=0");
    });
  } else { 
   select_element.focus();
  }
});
```

Things start to break when I add the following to the above code:

```
//this is the last row from above code before adding new code
xhttp.send("sites="+current_url+"&title="+current_title+"&vote_up=1&vote_down=0");

//this is new code
xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if(xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
    loadJSON(function(json) {
      var limit = json.length;
      var i = ((Math.floor(Math.random()*limit)+1) - 1);
      page = (json[i].sites);
      chrome.tabs[0].update(tab.id, {url: page});
    });
  }
}
```

When I add the above code, which should just be calling the first function, I start getting javascript error `Cannot read property 'url' of undefined`.

Se the question is... if javascript reads in a linear manner from top to bottom, why would the property become undefined with the addition of the `loadJSON(function(json)`? I can remove that function and everything works again. This is not a variable that is defined by the XMLHttpRequest so why would a nested request stop the variable from being loaded correctly?

More important how do I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you are using  `chrome.tabs.query` in two different ways. From the docs [`chrom.tabs.query(queryInfo, callback)` (Chrome Dev)](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/tabs/#method-query) takes as `callback` a function with a parameter of type [`Tab` (Chrome Dev)](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/tabs/#type-Tab) which is not iterable.

The first time you used it well:

```js
// "tab" as *singular*
chrome.tabs.query({currentWindow: true, active: true}, function (tab) { // <-- here 
      chrome.tabs.update(tab.id, {url: page});
});
```

But the second time you used it like an array:

```js
// "tabs" as *plural*?
chrome.tabs.query({active: true, lastFocusedWindow: true}, tabs => { // <-- here
      var current_url = tabs[0].url; // <-- tabs[0] is not defined!
      var current_title = tabs[0].title;
      var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xhttp.open("POST", "add.php", true);
      xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
      xhttp.send("sites="+current_url+"&title="+current_title+"&vote_up=1&vote_down=0");
});
```

A `Tab` object has no attribute `'0'` so by accessing `tabs[0]` you are actually retriving an `undefined`, which throws the error on the `url` property access

Comment: As stated in my post, this part of the code actually works perfect until I try to add an `xhttp.onreadystatechange`. 

So without the onreadystatechange, this will save the current_title and the current_url. So I am fairly sure that the array is not the problem, but I think you might be on the right track. Based on what you said I am thinknig its because I am calling tabs.update written in a function where its not an array, from inside a tabs array. 

So the question is, what other solutions exist for this problem.

Comment: Can you `console.log(tabs, tabs[0])`? Maybe you figure it out. Also can you add the error stack trace? Anyway I don't think this is the actual solution, but I have some suspects on `chrome.tabs[0].update(tab.id, {url: page});`

Comment: I don't understand why you answer is correct, but it is actually correct. ALthough it works as an array just fine when I try to call the callback it fails. When I redesign it not to use an array and instead to use `chrome.tabs.getSelected(null,function(tabs) {` it starts working perfectly.

Comment: @DDomen, query() always returns an array so your answer should be reversed. Always verify the [documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/tabs/#method-query). The question's problem is that the array is empty, which can happen when the current window is devtools (it should be closed prior to running the code). The first code wasn't failing because `([]).id` is undefined which means "the current tab" in chrome.tabs.update()